# How to set a fixed value to fields to a type?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

If I have this hierarchy of classes:

```
Class Shape
{
public bool closedPath;
}

class Circle : Shape
{
}
class Line: Shape
{
}
```

Here I know that all circles are closed paths.
How to set the value of `closedPath` field to these defaults without the need to assign its value when instantiating an object of that said class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare your closedPath as a virtual read-only property and then define it in descendant classes:

```
class Shape
{
    public virtual bool closedPath {get;}
}

class Circle : Shape
{
    public override bool closedPath => true;
}
class Line: Shape
{
    public override bool closedPath => false;
}
```

Things you might also consider are:

- changing your Shape class to the abstract class or to the IShape interface.
- You can also achieve the same result with a read-only field and initialize that field in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a value to the base constructor:

```
class Shape
{
    public bool closedPath;

    public Shape(bool closedPath)
    {
        this.closedPath = closedPath;
    }
}

class Circle : Shape
{
    public Circle()
        : base(true)
    {
    }
}

class Line : Shape
{
    public Line()
        : base(false)
    {
    }
}
```

Then you'd get:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    Shape circle = new Circle();
    Console.WriteLine(circle.closedPath);  // True

    Shape line = new Line();
    Console.WriteLine(line.closedPath);  // False
}
```